# How to import chinese characters from excel into oracle

Tags: oracle

How to import chinese characters from excel into oracle and also extract chinese characters from oracle into excel?

Comment: What is your database character set (SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET')?

Comment: And what version of Oracle, what's the client, what is you operating system?

Answer (score 0):

You would simply need to ensure that you have set Oracle to use a Unicode-compatible character encoding (I recommend UTF-8) and that no tool you are using to do the transfer is non-Unicode-safe.

Without knowing what you're using to do the transfer it's hard to give more specific information about where something is going wrong.

Comment: I think you mean UTF-16 as I'm sure chinese is like japanese and requires double byte characters to represent the full character set.

Comment: Dave, both UTF-8 and UTF-16 are multi-byte character encodings supporting the full Unicode repertoire.  Both should be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the database is setup with the correct character set to store/house chinese characters properly.  If the database can't store it then it pointless to imported it.  If the database can support the asian character set then set the client character set to a compatible one.   Once that is done the underline oci/odbc layer will handle the translation of one character set to the other as long as they are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following.

1. Database Character set (zhs16gbk)
2. Set the local variable to NLS_LANG=SIMPLIFIED CHINESE.CHINA_UTF8
3. Open the excel file save the file to unicode text
4. open the text file save the file to ANSI format
5. In the PLSQL developer, we have option called text importer. Using this tool we can import the data sucessfully